# How do I point to Node in a dockerized Django project using django-pipeline?

Tags: python, node.js, django, docker, django-pipeline

I'm trying to add [django-pipeline](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to a dockerized Django 3.1 project. However, when I run `collectstatic` I receive the following error:

```
pipeline.exceptions.CompressorError: b'/usr/bin/env: \xe2\x80\x98node\xe2\x80\x99:
No such file or directory\n'
```

My `settings.py` file includes:

```
PIPELINE = {
    'CSS_COMPRESSOR': 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor',
    'COMPILERS': ('pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',),
    'YUGLIFY_BINARY': str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('node_modules/.bin', 'yuglify')),
    'SASS_BINARY': str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('node_modules/.bin', 'sass')),
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'twirlmate': {
            'source_filenames': (
              'pages/scss/styles.css',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/styles.css',
        },
    },
}
```

And my `package.json` includes:

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.32.5",
    "yuglify": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have other local Django projects that use pipeline, but not Docker, and they work fine, so I'm wondering if it has to do with Node not being installed in the container? Any thoughts/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]

It turns out I was missing some commands in my `Dockerfile` to install nodejs:

```
# Dockerfile

...
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential

# Set working directory and install npm dependencies for pipeline
WORKDIR /code
RUN npm -g install sass
RUN npm -g install yuglify
```

`collectstatic` now works as expected.